# Editing Single Custom Post Type Title in Genesis

Tags: wordpress, hook, genesis

I'm having a bunch of trouble editing the title of a custom post type title in genesis. To get started I am using this code but I am having no luck:

```
add_filter( 'genesis_post_title_output', 'remove_single_custom_post_titles', 15 );
function remove_single_custom_post_titles( $title ) {
    $title .= 'This is what I want to add to the end';
    return $title;
}
```

Once I can just get this to be added to the end of the post I'm confident I can do whatever I need to be able to do.

Comment: if I use the the_title hook it just changes all of the titles on the page?

Comment: You need to add condition in your function so it is applied to your singular custom post type main loop only .. i.e is_singular('yourCPT') && is_main_query()

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'genesis_post_title_output', 'cpt_title_singular', 15 );
function cpt_title_singular( $title ) {

    if(is_singular('your-cpt-here') &&  is_main_query()){
            $title .= 'This is what I want to add to the end';
    }
            return $title;
        }
```

Note code is untested please check on localhost before applying on live site to avoid any typos. Main thing to note is `is_singular()` and `is_main_query()` tags to help you limit your title filter to only to specific CPT and main single post's title only.